# No sound from navigation apps while connected via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth-audio, navigation

I have the next issue with my Google Pixel 6 Pro. I use two nav apps - Google Maps and Waze. The sound from both of them are not audible while phone is connected via Bluetooth to my car, unless I start some song playing either in Spotify or Google Music. After song is started playing I need to turn off the nav app and run it again. Now the navigation audio will work and I can stop the music playing.

Any suggestions on how can I fix that? I've found multiple articles about "fixing navigation sound" but none helped me. Thank you!